How can I prevent customers from canceling their monthly subscriptions on Stripe until three months have passed?
I am implementing a subscription service using Stripe, and I want to enforce a policy where customers cannot cancel their monthly subscriptions until at least three months have passed since the subscription start date. How can I achieve this using Stripe API or any other available methods ? I want to ensure that customers adhere to this policy to reduce churn and maximize revenue. Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated.
i am creating a portal session in node js
  const session = await stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create({
      customer: customer.stripeCustomerId,
      return_url: 'https://my-website.com',
  });

I have created a customer poral session now i want my customers cannot cancel their monthly subscriptions until at least three months have passed since the subscription start date.

Create two Billing Portal Configurations: one that allows cancellation, and one that doesn't using this parameter.
Then, depending on how long the user was subscribed, create a Billing Portal with the correct configuration. Something like this:
const session = await stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create({
  customer: 'cus_xxx',
  return_url: 'https://example.com/account',
  configuration: canCancel ? 'bpc_xx1' : 'bpc_xx2', 
});

